# ¿Cómo hacer permutaciones en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando hacer unas permutaciones usando números en Javascript, pero no sé exactamente cómo empezar. Sé hacerlo en Python pero no he podido hacerlo en Javascript.

**Contexto**

Un textbox dice el tamaño de caracteres en la permutación

```
<input type="number" class="form-control input_number" id="tamanio_car" name="tamanio_car"></input>
```

Mi idea del input, es que cuando el usuario pone un numero, lo vea así.

```
Usuario pone 1 = 1 caracteres
Usuario pone 2 = 2 caracteres
Usuario pone 10 = 10 caracteres
```

Lo que necesito es buscar la manera de hacer un ciclo for que meta los numeros.Y los imprima uno a uno, es decir imprima todas las combinaciones posibles dependiendo del número de caracteres que pusó el usuario.

Es decir `0 1 2 3 4 5 etc hasta llegar a 9`

Es decir `01 02 03 10 11 etc hasta llegar a 99`

Este es el array que hice.

```
var numbersDB = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
```

Lo primero que intenté fue esto:

```
digitos = document.getElementById("tamanio_car").innerHTML;

for (var numero_inicio = 0; digitos.length < 10; numero_inicio++) {
    numero_inicio + 1
}
```

Pero no es lo que busco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que saber el largo del número transformandolo a String, y luego haces 2 for, uno con la iteración y otro para agregar ceros a la izquierda

El algoritmo sería el siguiente:

```js
const numeros=100;
const caracteres = String(numeros).length - 1;

for(let i = 0; i<numeros; i++){
  let res=""
  for(let j=0; j<caracteres-String(i).length; j++){
    res+="0";
    
  }
  console.log(res + i);
}
```

Empleando [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) de JS es aún más fácil

```js
const numeros=100;
const caracteres = String(numeros).length - 1;

for(let i = 0; i<12; i++){
  console.log(String(i).padStart(caracteres,0));
}
```